# What are best practices for in-app Facebook share?

Tags: mobile-application, facebook, sharing

What are best practices for implementing a share on Facebook feature in my app? I would like to enable users to share portions of my app (selected views) on Facebook.

Comment: could perhaps declare your assumptions, ideas, research and workflows, else we won't really be able to help out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends what you're trying to do; as @Xabre said, without knowing what you're trying to do, it's hard to help you.

At the most generic level, you should follow Facebook's sharing guidelines: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices